# Creating and Verifying JWT signature using public/private key in Spring boot security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I would like to know the process of creation and verification of JWT signature using public and private keys in spring boot security.

I am trying to validate JWT token using HMAC algorithm. I am building JWT with hardcoded secret "MYSECRET".

```
Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setAudience(audience)
                .setIssuedAt(createdDate)
                .setExpiration(expirationDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "MYSECRET")
                .compact()
```

For parsing the code is as follows

```
Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey("MYSECRET")
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
```

Instead of using signing key as "MYSECRET", I would like to make use of public and private keys

Comment: Your code is not using spring security, it is using `jjwt` library, that can be used with spring or not. Alternatively spring has its own JWT implementation. Do you want to adapt your code to use a key pair or re-implement all?

Answer (score 11):

- Generate JKS Java KeyStore File

Let’s first generate the keys – and more specifically a .jks file – using the command line tool keytool:

> keytool -genkeypair -alias mytest 
>                       -keyalg RSA 
>                       -keypass mypass 
>                       -keystore mytest.jks 
>                       -storepass mypass

- Export your public key

> keytool -list -rfc --keystore mytest.jks | openssl x509 -inform pem
>   -pubkey

Using your key to sign token in your Authorization Server.

```
@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter(){

    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = 
      new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("mytest.jks"), "mypass".toCharArray());
    converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("mytest"));
    return converter;
}
```

Finally using your public key in your resource server.

```
@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public.txt");
    String publicKey = null;
    try {
        publicKey = IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    converter.setVerifierKey(publicKey);
    return converter;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this with out using OAuth?

Comment: Oauth2 can use JWT (or not), but it is not required to implement a JWT authentication system using an asymmetric key pair

Comment: JWT we can implement with JWT that is fine! We call stateless it could make your app scalability because your resources sever no need to check token in database they just verify the key is enough!

Comment: @user8363477 if you don’t want to use The oauth2 you just use they private key and publicly by reading the file instead your secret! It will work i also use that !

Comment: Can you provide more description? Actually i'm first time work on multi module project and i don't have idea how my second module request should be authorize.

Comment: So you have multiple module. The resource server and authorization server is the same maven project?